# nginx ini file throwing error (Permission denied [core/socket.c line 230])

Tags: python, nginx, uwsgi, ubuntu-16.04

When we run .ini file with sudo it's working fine. But without sudo it throwing following error,

```
/home/ubuntu/.local/bin/uwsgi
!!! no internal routing support, rebuild with pcre support !!!
your processes number limit is 29858
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
bind(): Permission denied [core/socket.c line 230]
```

Tried re-installing uwsgi but still it showing same error.
We set 777 permission for that folder still same error.

Comment: If sudo is working and not-sudo is failing, then you have a permission issue. Try setting the 777 to entire folder and all its contents. Also, there could be a tool, command file, something that you're using that doesn't have execute privileges. Keep searching and you'll find it.

Comment: i tried this...but still same issue

Answer (score 3):

Edit: Actually, sorry, this'll be the permission on the UNIX socket. You should check your UNIX socket file (Who owns the socket, what's the group on it, what the permissions, what user are you trying to run, etc).

Edit 2: potentially relevant uWSGI config docs - http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Options.html?highlight=socket-chmod#chmod-socket

---

Previous wrong answer, it's where socket.c is trying to access the UNIX socket:

The permission error is in the socket library when it's trying to bind to a port (I'm assuming it's port 80).

`bind(): Permission denied [core/socket.c line 230]`

Ports 0-1024 are restricted to root. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16564/why-are-the-first-1024-ports-restricted-to-the-root-user-only